# Escaping script in underscore template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, delimiter

I have the following:

```
<p><%- body %></p>
```

Body can consist of anything, it isn't checked anywhere else except here. The <%- does a good job until I try using underscore delimiters in the body. Something like this from user input will not allow the body to render:

```
<% print("<sc" + "ript type='text/javascript'>"); %>$('html')<% print("</sc"+"ript>"); %>
```

How can I fully escape the body so it doesn't execute in the template?

Comment: So you have `<% print(... %>` in `body`? What happens to `<%- body %>` when you do that? Maybe a complete example (preferably with a runnable snippet, jsfiddle.net example, jsbin.com example, ...) would help.

Comment: I don't understand. The content of `body` is (should) never evaluated as a template string?